# how to get the value in the tag using the attribute name and tag name in java DOM parser

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

this is the xml

```
<a>  
  <b name="dataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClass">oracle</property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">jdb:</property>
  </b>
</a>
```

how to get the value in the tag using the attribute name

for example :oracle

```
<property name="driverClass">oracle</property>
```

using tagname **property**  and attribute value **driverClass**

i want to get **oracle**

Comment: Do you want ALL nodes with attribute or just the `property` nodes?  Do the `property` nodes need be children of `b` who are children of `a`?

Comment: i need only property node value  using atribute value

Comment: yes property node need to be children of b which is a child of a

Answer (score 1):

You can use a XPath query, something like `/a/b/property[@name='driverClass']/text()` which will return the text value of the `property` node, which has an attribute `name` equal to `driverClass` and which is a of child `b`, which is a child of `a`

For example...

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(JavaApplication244.class.getResourceAsStream("/Test.xml"));

    XPathFactory xf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xf.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile("/a/b/property[@name='driverClass']/text()");
    String value = expression.evaluate(doc);
    System.out.println(value);
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs `oracle`

Have a look at [w3schools, xPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) and [How XPath Works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) for some more details

Comment: @user2741894 Glad it could help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

XML input:

```
< nodename attribute="value" > Something </ nodename>
```

Java code:

```
NodesList subs = child.item(j).getChildNodes();

System.out.println(subs.item(0).getTextContent()); // >> Something
```